# Phantom wont initialize/loaded angularjs controller methods

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, phantomjs

i need help creating a pdf file off a html page powered by an angularjs controller. the pdf will be created by using phantom module. im able to display and bind data correctly as soon as i navigate to the specific url, but when i call phantom to render the page it doesnt load/initiliaze/call the controller methods i have tried different methods such as doing ng-init from the div or calling a function from the controller once is done loading or even using

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
  //code here...
})
```

phantom code:

```
function DoThePDF(){
    phantom.create(function(ph){
        ph.createPage(function(page) {
            page.set("paperSize", { format: "A4", orientation: 'portrait', margin: '1cm' });
            page.open(address, function(status) {
                if(status !== 'success'){
                    console.log('unable to open webpage');
                }
                else{
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        page.render("reports.pdf");
                        console.log("page rendered");
                        ph.exit();
                    }, 5000);
                }
            })
        })
    });
}
```

when calling page.open(address, function(status) {...} i can see that the page is been opened but the angular events/methods dont get initialized/called so when the page gets rendered is an empty html template no data gets binded. i have added delays but still it doesnt help.

Comment: Please register to the [`onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html), [`onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html), [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors. Note that registering is a little [different](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node/wiki#page-settings-callbacks-properties) by using the bridge.

Comment: apparently phantom uses very old sockets that are not compatible with the sockets im using and there for can't load page correctly.

Comment: PhantomJS 1.x doesn't support websockets. You can compile PhantomJS 2. It should be in a state that is usable as a beta version. Don't forget to answer your own question with all your results and the path that you took to determine this.

Comment: approach 1: compile phantomJS2 unknown state. approach 2: build webpage on server side using angularjs-server and by the time phamton requests the page is already load and no need to communicate with websockets. i will post my final solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhantomJS 1.9.x doesn't support websocket, therefor i have to use PhantomJS 2. there is not an official release yet since is being developed but there a beta version 
[Here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/tree/master) build as specified. Good luck